# find the cells around an array of cells in Java

Tags: java, arrays, uitableview, indexing

I am developing a battleship game and I'm searching a way to calculate the cells that are around my boat.
Because **boats(++++)** can't be perpendicular or adjacent to each other so I'm calculating invalid **cells(====)** that warp my ship.They are JButton and I can calculate the **index**,color of the cell to find if there is already a boat or not.

```
|====|====|====|====|====|

|====|++++|++++|++++|====|

|====|====|====|====|====|
```

Comment: I think you have the position, where the user want set a boat. Than you check possible fields around it. Simple but works ;)

Comment: yes i'm asking how to check possible fields

Comment: You have a start coordinate x/y and you must check the fields around it. +x / +y / -x / -y.